# c++/Operating System - How to find the code of an executable when it is running

Tags: c++, xcode, process, operating-system

So when we execute a program, the operating system allocates some memory for the main process of the executable and then loads the code of the executable into this memory so that it can be fetched and executed by the processor.

My question is, where can I find this code?

More precisely,

- Can I look at it using a debugger, say Visual studio or Xcode?
- Can I access and read/write it with my own code? If so how do I do that?
  Or is it protected by the operating system?

EDIT: To be more precise, the first step I would like to achieve is this:

I am using Xcode on mac and when I run the debugger, I can look at the memory: 
Debug -> Debug Workflow -> View Memory

It opens a window with the raw memory of the program and I can look at specific adresses.

- Can I look at the code in this memory view?
- At which address should I look to look at the code in memory?

Comment: You can attach to any process running under your login, but what you're going to see when you break the running code is going to be machine language.

Comment: Google: `site:stackoverflow.com xcode view disassembly` should reveal the "look at the code" trick